# How to classify each datapoint in a timeseries using deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, supervised-learning, attention

I am new to time series but for my project I wonder if there is something along those lines:
My aim is to classify each datapoint of a time-dependent time series. In practical terms, I have arrays of variable lengths. Those capture the progression of a signal in time. Now I want to use deep learning to classify the different "segments" within the input data. My input data is labeled, so I have a 2 x length matrix with x values in the first row and the corresponding y value (for each x value) in the 2. row. I want to train on those arrays and classify unseen data. My thoughts were that CNNs or any attention based Model could do so, however all papers I've come across so far classify a whole timeseries into a class. I don't want to cut my data, since the time dependence is important, so my question is whether this is somehow feasible? Any paper (with code preferably) recommendation is most welcome:)